# Blender Icing Render always white

Tags: rendering

In the rendering screen the frosting is the color it should be but when I press F12 it turns white. I'm not sure what the cause of it is. Can anyone help?

New to the website so idk how to reply. The add comment button does nothing. >_< My donut doesn't have a second icing object hidden or anything.

Added pictures for reference cuz idk how to explain it any better than I did.
https://gyazo.com/85c7104112ed116fcd49b01b064b342f

https://gyazo.com/e805f22e9d38911cc6c49d1ea6594e60 This is what happens when I press F12 to get it to render. Why does the frosting turn white???

Comment: Is there any chance you have a second "icing" object that is hidden in the viewport? Objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added pictures for reference cuz idk how to explain it any better than I did. https://gyazo.com/85c7104112ed116fcd49b01b064b342f

https://gyazo.com/e805f22e9d38911cc6c49d1ea6594e60 This is what happens when I press F12 to get it to render. Why does the frosting turn white???

Comment: please just copy/paste pictures directly in your question. No need to use links. Please provide blend file, so we can check it out.

Comment: How do I upload a blend file here?

Comment: [How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)

Comment: Hope this worked. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DQ1jaBgA" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DQ1jaBgA/)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Will posting the images as embed files actually help me? Cuz I've posted the images as links, which means you *can* see it, but people are still stooped. If no one can answer can I be directed to somewhere that possibly could?

Answer (score 0):

You have set a keyframe on the base color of the icing material. Therefore, whenever a frame update happens the adjusted value is reset to the keyframed value.

Right-click the color selection box and clear the keyframe. Then you can proceed as normal.

[image: Image showing how to clear keyframes]